# Mathias URL shortener

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, url-shortener

I am using this URL shortener but I'm having a hard time setting it up.
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/php-url-shortener

I've setup the database, changed the config file accordingly. I put the files in a subdirectory and removed Rewritebase from the .htaccess file.

I'm not sure what these two scripts mean if anyone could help?
`## Favelets / Bookmarklets

#### Prompt

// js
`javascript:(function(){var%20q=prompt('URL:');if(q){document.location='http://yourshortener.ext/shorten?url='+encodeURIComponent(q)}}());`

#### Shorten this URL

// js
`javascript:(function(){document.location='http://yourshortener.ext/shorten?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)}());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts you're asking about are there so you can quickly create a Short URL from that page.

The prompt will ask you what URL you want to shorten, whilst the second one will automatically shorten the page you're already on.

Give them a go :)

Comment: When I try using it in an input value, it doesn't seem to work. It just spits out the javascript.
`<input id="fe_text" type="text" value="javascript:(function(){document.location='http://chrisburton.me/shorten?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)}());" />`

Comment: If you want to visibly display the code so the user can copy it, you need to encode that JavaScript so it wont execute.

Comment: Would you mind ticking this answer if it's helped you please?

Answer (score -1):

If you Uploaded all files to your host then replace

> ### http://yourshortener.ext/shorten?url=
>
> With
>
> ### http://Yourdomain.com/shorten?url=